# работа цикла for с random

Tags: java

```
public class Lottery{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] nums = new int[50];
    for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++){
        nums[i]=i;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++){
        int r = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*49); // ВОТ допустим получили 5
        int temp = nums[i];  // здесь стал темп = 1
        nums[i] = nums[r];   // [.. 5 .. .. .. .. .. ..] - так получается место в памяти массива заняла у нас цифра 5 для позиции в массиве по циклу это первая позиция. 
        nums[r] = temp;      // - это тогда для чего?
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) System.out.print(Integer.toString(nums[i]) + " ");
}
```

}

Comment: Если ваш вопрос это тот, который в комментариях кода, то эти три строки с `temp` - это обычный способ поменять местами два значения, `nums[i]` и `nums[r]` в данном случае.

Comment: да, в комментариях, но для чего он нужно в данном случае?

Comment: Алгоритм пытается перемешать массив. Похож на тасование Фишера — Йетса, но реализован неправильно. Если интересно, можете поискать правильную реализацию, например на википедии https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: Да. Это перемешивание. Только случайное число должно быть от i до 49.

Comment: Я понял так что после присваивания первого элемента массива он ему обратно порядковый номер записывает. т.е. дошли до 2 ячейки проделали операцию и вернули обратно как оно и было.

Comment: Так вопросы не задают. Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: А в чем вопрос?